# Very weak signal rlt8723be Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: wireless, drivers, 15.10, realtek

I've been trying to get Ubuntu to run on my HP 15-an000nd.
It has been a huge pain all the way.

My last (big) remaining problem is Wi-Fi. The signal strength is very very weak. 
lspci gives me the following concerning wireless:

```
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 522a (rev 01)
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 0a)
```

I have tried the following:

```
sudo rmmod rtl8723be && sudo modprobe rtl8723be
```

and it tried to install these drivers: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new

I also set this parameter in the config file :

```
options rtl8723be fwlps=0
```

but nothing helps I still barely get any signal.

Any help is greatly appreciated,
Greetings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install this driver from another branch of this github called `rock.new_btcoex` and use `ant_sel=2` parameter.

Alternatively you can uninstall that  driver by running `sudo make uninstall` and install a driver from PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf <<< "options rtl8723be ant_sel=2"
```

This problem happens with 1 antenna laptops. The driver does not detect to which slot the antenna is attached. So you are using the adapter without an antenna. The last command should fix it.

Older versions of this driver do not have this parameter. You can check if it is there or not by

```
modinfo rtl8723be | grep parm
```

Comment: i did a fresh install of ubuntu and then used the ppa to install the driver, then i did a reboot. then i changed the antenna to 2 and rebooted.  still no joy :(. might the antenna be connected to another slot ?

Comment: Sorry, I omitted important part of the command. I fixed it now. Try again the last command.

Comment: you are my hero ! many thanks !
just one edit for the ones that might have the same problem, you made a typo, you meant: sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms

Comment: Good catch! Fixed that too.